# Create list of custom object inline, without seperate model class - java

Tags: java

To keep code minimal, I want to be able to create a list of a custom object in java. Similar to what we do in `C#` or `Swift`, where we define the constructor or parameters of the list in that way we don't have to create a separate object and constructor for the list.

**For example**

```
    var menuList: [(category: String, name: String, ismulti: Bool)] = [
      (category: "Categ1", name: "name1", ismulti: true),
      (category: "Categ2", name: "name2",  ismulti: false),
      (category: "Categ3", name: "name3", type: ismulti: true),
    ]
```

Here `var menuList: [(category: String, name: String, ismulti: Bool)]` reduced the need for object and constructor. Is there something similar in java?

**for same what I did in java.**

```
public class Menu{
    String category;
    String name;
    boolean isMulti;

    public Menu(String category, String name, boolean isMulti) {
        this.category = category;
        this.name = name;
        this.isMulti = isMulti;
    }

    public List<Menu> menuList = new ArrayList<Menu>() {{
        add(new Menu("categ1","name1",true));
        add(new Menu("categ2","name2",true));
        add(new Menu("categ3","name3",true));

    }};
}
```

Comment: Note that the *records* feature does almost exactly what you're looking for. It is in preview in Java 14 and planned for full support in Java 16.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth mentioning what this syntax is:

```
public List<Menu> menuList = new ArrayList<Menu>() {{
    add(new Menu("categ1","name1",true));
    add(new Menu("categ2","name2",true));
    add(new Menu("categ3","name3",true));

}}
```

This is called - "double brace initialization" and under the hood it anonymously extends ArrayList class, generally it should be used with caution, you could read more [here](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/)

Back to the original question - depending on what you need, which version of java you are using and whether you can/want to use some external libraries, you have this options, note that `Arrays.asList()` and `List.of()` return a list that does not support all of the operations, like `add()` or `remove()` and in case of the latter, also `set()`.
Also regarding constructor, as others already mentioned, you could use [project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to generate constructor for you.:

### Java 9

```
List<Menu> collect = List.of(
new Menu("categ1","name1",true),
new Menu("categ2","name2",true),
new Menu("categ3","name3",true));
```

### Java 8

```
List<Menu> collect = Stream.of(
new Menu("categ1","name1",true),
new Menu("categ2","name2",true),
new Menu("categ3","name3",true))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### Java before 8

```
List<Menu> collect = Arrays.asList(
            new Menu("categ1", "name1", true),
            new Menu("categ2", "name2", true),
            new Menu("categ3", "name3", true));
```

### Using Guava

Guava is an external library, see it [here](https://github.com/google/guava).

```
List<Menu> collect = Lists.newArrayList(
    new Menu("categ1","name1",true),
    new Menu("categ2","name2",true),
    new Menu("categ3","name3",true));
```

Alternatively you could write your own class like @ernest_k did, which really gives you nice flexibility when working with different types.

Comment: thanks for pointing out "double brace initialization".

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a third workaround (as the other answers have pointed out, you can't do this in Java - there's no such syntax).

One thing you can do is create your own *reusable* `Tuple` class. You'll be forced to have a class per number of elements, but you can reuse it with various combinations of types.

```
static class Tuple3<T, U, V> {
    final T _1;
    final U _2;
    final V _3;

    private Tuple3(T t, U u, V v) {
        this._1 = t;
        this._2 = u;
        this._3 = v;
    }

    public static <T, U, V> Tuple3<T, U, V> of(T t, U u, V v) {
        return new Tuple3<>(t, u, v);
    }
}
```

Then (with the same tuple class, you can have different flavors of this):

```
//menuList is a List<Tuple3<String, String, Boolean>>
var menuList = List.of(
    Tuple3.of("Categ1", "name1", true), 
    Tuple3.of("Categ2", "name2", false),
    Tuple3.of("Categ3", "name3", true)
);

//registration is a List<Tuple3<String, LocalDate, Double>>
var registrationData = List.of(
    Tuple3.of("John", LocalDate.EPOCH, 1.1), 
    Tuple3.of("James", LocalDate.now(), 2.2),
    Tuple3.of("Ron", LocalDate.now(), 3.3)
);
```

I personally would make fields `_1`, `_2`, and `_3` public, but this is a preference. You can create getters for them if you prefer (perhaps `_1()` but it can't get clean enough.

---

*I'm assuming Java 11+, but you can easily make it compatible with older versions by just dropping `var` and `List.of`*

Comment: Thanks for the workaround solution, I wonder why we miss such a basic thing in java.

Comment: @AmirDora. Yeah... And I don't think this will come to the language any time soon if it will at all. This solution was just an attempt to emulate what other jvm languages like Scala have (but they provide native syntax for tuple literals on top of it)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to [generate the constructor](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) for you. That does not really solve your problem, but at least you have shorter code.

And you could use the diamond operator for `new ArrayList<>()` or use `Arrays.asList()` to create a new List.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Menu {
    String category;
    String name;
    boolean isMulti;

    public List<Menu> menuList = List.of( // if Java < 9, use Arrays.asList()
            new Menu("categ1", "name1", true),
            new Menu("categ2", "name2", true),
            new Menu("categ3", "name3", true)
    );
}
```

Comment: Note that the list created bt `Arrays.asList` does not support `add` and `remove` methods. If Java 9 is available, I would recommend using `List.of` instead, more expressive.

Comment: Thanks, much better than my code, but I think a lot of people are hesitant to use libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Java authors prefer such design for sake of simplicity. Yes, it looks verbose for most of the developers but the regularity of the syntax with the minimal use of syntactic sugar is more programming error free and less complex. Therefore better for maintainability IMHO.

To answer you how to reduce the bolerplate with the pure Java, **you can't**. Hoever, there are tools and ways to make the whole code look more compact and don't lose the track about what is going code in the code.

1. Avoid the block initialized. A lot of developers get confused when they see it. Use `Arrays.asList()` or `List.of()` as of Java 9:

   ```
   public List<Menu> menuList = List.of(
       new Menu("categ1","name1",true),
       new Menu("categ2","name2",true),
       new Menu("categ3","name3",true)
   );
   ```
2. Use [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) commonly used to eliminate the common boilerplate such as constructors, getters etc. using the advantage of the annotation-processor and the annotations [`@AllArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) etc.

The whole code becomes both easy to read and easy to maintain:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Menu {

    String category;
    String name;
    boolean isMulti;

    public List<Menu> menuList = List.of(
        new Menu("categ1","name1",true),
        new Menu("categ2","name2",true),
        new Menu("categ3","name3",true)
    );
}
```